# How to make a Windows 8 XAML data entry form?

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I need to make a form in XAML on Windows 8 for entering an address.  I don't need the "Contact Person" header, but this is how it should look:

[image]

The example is from [an HTML5 Forms demo for IE](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/Forms/Default.html).

I tried a 2 column Grid, but the TextBlocks and TextBoxes don't easily line up.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: A Grid with two columns would be the way to go here.  What do you mean when you say that the TextBlocks and TextBoxes "don't easily line up"?

Comment: I think you should give a chance to HorizontalAlignment property. You can set this to right/left and forget about columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you could do it using a `Grid` which seems a good solution for me:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Name:" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="John Doe"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Address:" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="1 Microsoft Way"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="City:" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Redmond"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="State:" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text=""/>
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Row="4" Text="Zip Code:" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="98052"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Row="5" Text="Email Address:" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="john.doe@microsoft.com"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Row="6" Text="Telephone Number:" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Margin="2" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Text="(425) 333-4444"/>
</Grid>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Aren't the `TextBlock`s and `TextBox`es lined up okay?

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, you can get that "Contact Person" box by surrounding Damir Arh's answer with a [GroupBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `GroupBox` is not available in Windows 8 applications.  It would work for a WPF application, or Windows Form application, however.